# creating a table in Apex Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

how to create table in apex page
I have this code

```
<apex:page controller="SettingRules" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        
        <h1>Object field information</h1>
        
        <tr>
            <td>Object name : </td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!nameObject}" /><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <table>

            <tr>
                <th>Field Name</th>
                <th>Rule</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>                
                <apex:repeat value="{!ruleForObjectMapGetter}" var="objectKey">
                <tr>
                    
                    <td>{!objectKey}</td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!ruleForObjectMapGetter[objectKey]}" var="rule">
                            isEnabled={!rule.isEnabled},<br/>
                            ryleDescription={!rule.ryleDescription},<br/>
                            ryleName={!rule.ryleName},<br/>
                            ryleTitle={!rule.ryleTitle},<br/>
                            ryleType={!rule.ryleType}<br/>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </td>
            
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

It all looks like this
[image]

I would like to add some styling to make it all look more readable, but I don't have enough experience with Apex Page. Please tell me how to do something like this

[image]